# Firefox Storage Access API denies local storage after successful requestStorageAccess() call

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, iframe, storage-access-api

I want to test the new [Firefox Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API#Storage_Access_API_methods) to allow 1st party storage (cookie, local storage, indexeddb, ...) to an iframe of a different domain (but still under my control).

### Parent Markup / code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Parent Domain</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jschannel/1.0.0-git-commit1-8c4f7eb/jschannel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Cookies: <ul class="cookie-data"></ul>
        </div>
        <iframe 
            id="rpc-gateway"
            src="http://child.local:8080/iframe-firefox.html"
            sandbox="allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
            var chan = Channel.build({
                window: document.getElementById("rpc-gateway").contentWindow,
                origin: "*",
                scope: "testScope"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Child Iframe Markup / code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Child Domain</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jschannel/1.0.0-git-commit1-8c4f7eb/jschannel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="onLoginClick()">Login</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chan = Channel.build({
                window: window.parent,
                origin: "*",
                scope: "testScope"
            });

            let onLoginClick = function(trans, params) {
                document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
                    if (!hasAccess) {
                        console.log("no access - requesting access");
                        return document.requestStorageAccess();
                    }
                }).then(_ => {
                    document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
                        console.log("hasAccess:", hasAccess);
                        window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
                    })
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("hasStorageAccess() failed", err);
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the "Login" button from the Child Iframe, the following log output is generated:

```
no access - requesting access      # iframe-firefox.html:22:25
hasAccess: true      # iframe-firefox.html:27:25
Request to access cookie or storage on “http://child.local:8080/iframe-firefox.html” was blocked because we are blocking all third-party storage access requests and content blocking is enabled.      # iframe-firefox.html:28:24
```

The visible conclusion is:

- The promise document.hasStorageAccess() resolves
- The hasAccess parameter is initially 'false'
- The promise of document.requestStorageAccess() is returned and resolves
- The 2nd promise document.hasStorageAccess() resolves
- The hasAccess parameter is now 'true'
- nevertheless, simple storage access to local storage is not possible.

What do I do wrong?

More Info's:

- Firefox Developer Edition Version 65.0b9
- Content Blocking Setting: [image: Content Blocking Setting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the version of Firefox you're using. I set up a test locally of what you have and in Firefox 69.0.1 (64 bit), I get no error and the value is stored to local storage. When I took the sandbox flag `allow-storage-access-by-user-activation` out of the parent iframe, the child failed to get permission for local storage, so that confirms that my setup was actually working properly. Here's what I did:

Created a Node.js/Express server for the parent:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const server = express();

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

Created a Node.js/Express server for the child (with different port to trigger same origin policy):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const server = express();

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

server.listen(8081, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:8081');
});
```

Created an index.html for the parent (pretty much the same as yours):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Parent Domain</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jschannel/1.0.0-git-commit1-8c4f7eb/jschannel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Cookies: <ul class="cookie-data"></ul>
        </div>
        <iframe
            id="rpc-gateway"
            src="http://127.0.0.1:8081/iframe-firefox.html"
            sandbox="allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chan = Channel.build({
                window: document.getElementById("rpc-gateway").contentWindow,
                origin: "*",
                scope: "testScope"
            });

            // Added this to try out the JSChannel
            chan.call({
                method: "reverse",
                params: "hello world!",
                success: function(v) {
                    console.log(v);
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And created iframe-firefox.html for the child:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Child Domain</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jschannel/1.0.0-git-commit1-8c4f7eb/jschannel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="onLoginClick()">Login</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chan = Channel.build({
                window: window.parent,
                origin: "*",
                scope: "testScope"
            });

            // Other end of the JSChannel call
            chan.bind("reverse", function(trans, s) {
                return s.split("").reverse().join("");
            });

            let onLoginClick = function(trans, params) {
                document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
                    if (!hasAccess) {
                        console.log("no access - requesting access");
                        return document.requestStorageAccess();
                    }
                }).then(_ => {
                    document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
                        console.log("hasAccess:", hasAccess);
                        window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
                    })
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("hasStorageAccess() failed", err);
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And everything worked as expected... So I'm feeling pretty sure that the issue is with the specific version of Firefox Developer Edition that you're using.

Also, here's a link to a zip of my setup if you want to give it a try on your end and see if this works differently than what you have: [server.zip](https://mega.nz/#!0eoUTShJ!sS8ASWkyc8jMCHdgRbjs7m7uB_OVfh4jpamU6d3pUPA)

Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help.

Comment: Amazing work!  Know any way to get this example working on Safari's Storage Access API?

Comment: @KelseyHannan I just looked at the feature availability on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=requestStorageAccess) and this should work just fine as is for Safari. You might want to add a couple of checks to make sure the document object has requestStorageAccess() and hasStorageAccess() methods so you don't get errors on browsers that don't support it though.

Comment: The Storage Access API works in Safari, but it only affects cookies, not local storage.
"WebKit’s implementation of the API only covers cookies for now. It does not affect the partitioning of other storage forms such as IndexedDB or LocalStorage."
https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/